# Responsive topnav

Tags: html, css

When I make the browser window smaller, the topnav don`t follow and match accordingly. What I want is a responsive topnav. What am I doing wrong? Will it automaticaly fit a mobile screen, but not a browser window? But then again, it works at w3schools. Posted now with the HTML.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #141A34;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

ul li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

ul li.right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.topnav li.right,
  ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
  }
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="ferskvaregrossisten.html">Hjem</a></li>
  <li><a href="om.html">Om</a></li>
  <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Produkter</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="kjøttvarer.html">Kjøttvarer</a>
      <a href="pølser.html">Pølser</a>
      <a href="pålegghelpølse.html">Pålegg hel pølse</a>
      <a href="kryddersmør.html">Kryddersmør</a>
      <a href="pakketpålegg.html">Pakket pålegg</a>
      <a href="kjølevarer.html">Kjølevarer</a>
      <a href="kjølevarerfiskogskalldyr.html">Kjølevarer fisk og skalldyr</a>

</ul>
```

Comment: from what i see, this may not solve the problem entirely but close the list after the "produckter</a>"

Comment: @Zappoh add `topnav` class to your `ul` it should working fine (see you have `topnav` in your *media queries*)...

Comment: I removed topnav, from the media queries. That worked!

Comment: This also helped:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `<div>` and your `<li>`. Try the following html:

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="ferskvaregrossisten.html">Hjem</a></li>
      <li><a href="om.html">Om</a></li>
      <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Produkter</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="kjøttvarer.html">Kjøttvarer</a>
        <a href="pølser.html">Pølser</a>
        <a href="pålegghelpølse.html">Pålegg hel pølse</a>
        <a href="kryddersmør.html">Kryddersmør</a>
        <a href="pakketpålegg.html">Pakket pålegg</a>
        <a href="kjølevarer.html">Kjølevarer</a>
        <a href="kjølevarerfiskogskalldyr.html">Kjølevarer fisk og skalldyr</a>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Strange, the menu looks to me like it fits to the screen width, even when you resize it. Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfeferman/yt6vbzwt/). Perhaps I'm not understanding the issue.

Comment: Now it worked for me to, but only with one menu item going under the other when I resized the browser window. When I view it on a mobile phone that doesn`t happen at all.

Comment: If you want to prevent the menu items from wrapping underneath each other, you can do the following: add `white-space:nowrap;` to the `ul` rule and change the `ul li` rule to `ul li {display:inline-block;}`.

Comment: No, I want them to go underneath each other,

Comment: I see, it already does that when you resize a desktop window small enough. Haven't tested on mobile. But you could resort to @media directive to adjust according to different screen resolutions, as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `className` to your 'ul'

In your media queries, you use `ul.topnav`, but in HTML, your `ul` doesn't have that className